# Return lagrange multiplier of scipy.minimize using slsqp

Tags: scipy

Is there a way to get the multipliers back from scipy.minimize when using the slsqp method? Or is there any other method which can be used for constraint optimization and returning the multipliers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can treat your Lagrange multiplier as variable along with the variables from your objective function. Have a look in the following link:

[Numpy arange error with Lagrange Multiplier in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41634979/numpy-arange-error-with-lagrange-multiplier-in-python)